# Relational database: What is the formal word for the thing a tale row represents?

Tags: relational-database

I am writing a manual for an sql stored procedure, and I want to be as accurate as possible, though I haven't had much training in relational database theory. I know that tables represent entities. I need to know what does a record/row represent. I guess it will be entity something: maybe entity object? Entity instantiation?

I am re-stating my problem to its exact nature: I have a table named customer in my db. I need to insert rows into another database, which has also a similar named table. However, my database has one row per customer; if i change something on a row, I do an sql update. If I change something to the other db, I ought not to do an update, but to make an entire new row, and there is a special field named status which should have the value of "change" in that case.

...and my entire problem is to try to describe this in a formal specification. So my try until now is: "For every entity instantiation(???) of our database corresponds a set of records of the other database, each of which actually represents an insert/update command, and not the entity itself"

Comment: An entity is usually an instantiated object representing a single record.  The class or code template which describes that entity would correspond to the table definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What tables or rows represent depend on your data modeling discipline.

When talking about the representation of entities, it's necessary to distinguish between the identity and the extension of entities. Naive data models tend to focus on the extent of entities as primary, whereas logical models merely identify entities in relation to each other. In both cases, we can say that entities are being represented. The difference is that logical models organize knowledge *about* entities, whereas naive data models try to capture the entities themselves.

In the relational database model, tables represent relations / predicates and rows represent propositions - the values in each row satisfy the roles / placeholders in the table's predicate statement to make a true statement. Entities correspond to values, entity sets to domains.

In the entity-relationship model, tables represent either entity relations or relationship relations. Entity sets are represented by their primary keys, relationship sets are represented by composite keys. Rows represent attribute values of entities or relationships.

In the network data model, tables represent entity sets, rows represent individual entities. References between rows represent relationships. This seems to be the model you're coming from. However, this approach is the oldest and most naive of these three and frequently requires artificial entities to be created to overcome it's limited ability to represent complex relationships, making ontological interpretations of the data model difficult.

If you need to write formal specifications, I recommend you study the relational model of data, which is the most expressive of the three and equivalent to first order predicate logic in power. Take a look at [object-role modeling](http://orm.net/) and books like Lex de Haan and Toon Koppelaar's *Applied mathematics for database professionals*. Bill Kent's *Data and reality* also offers much insight into the difficulties of modeling the real world.

Comment: Gee, that was heavy! I guess I was asking for it. Thank you, I'll keep this as a starting point for future readings.